# VBA Web Scraping behind Login

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have an issue running a VBA code to extract data from behind a webpage login. the login webpage I am receiving an error with is https://ft.lytx.com/.  I keep receiving an "error 91: object variable or with block variable not set." I am also receiving a "run time error 462: the remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.

```
Sub Login()

Const Url$ = "https://ft.lytx.com/"

Dim username As String
Dim Password As String
Dim LoginData As Worksheet
Set LoginData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
username = LoginData.Cells(1, "B").Value
Password = LoginData.Cells(2, "B").Value

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie

    .Navigate Url
    ieBusy ie
    .Visible = True

    Dim ologin As Object
    Dim oPassword As Object
    Set ologin = .Document.getElementsByName("username")(0)
    Set oPassword = .Document.getElementsByName("Password")(0)
    

    ologin = username
    oPassword.Value = Password
    .Document.forms(0).submit
    
    End With
    
    End Sub
    
Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. use getElementByID instead of name, they have IDs,its better and you dont have to specify the index (0). 2. You have ologin = username instead of ologin.value = username. 3. I am too lazy to paste this on excel, care to let us know which lines are throwing the error codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must insert a manual break after the IE reports it's ready because there is some dynamic content that loads after that. You also have to trigger some html events. Another thing is, you can't submit the form in the way you try. You must click the submit button.

I have no account for the page but I think this should work:

```
Sub Login()

Const Url$ = "https://ft.lytx.com/"

Dim ie As Object
Dim nodeUsername As Object
Dim nodePassword As Object
Dim username As String
Dim password As String
Dim loginData As Worksheet

  Set loginData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  username = loginData.Cells(1, "B").Value
  password = loginData.Cells(2, "B").Value
  
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Navigate Url
  ie.Visible = True
  Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5))
  
  Set nodeUsername = ie.document.getElementByID("username")
  Call TriggerEvent(ie.document, nodeUsername, "compositionstart")
  nodeUsername.Value = username
  Call TriggerEvent(ie.document, nodeUsername, "compositionend")
  
  Set nodePassword = ie.document.getElementByID("password")
  Call TriggerEvent(ie.document, nodePassword, "compositionstart")
  nodePassword.Value = password
  Call TriggerEvent(ie.document, nodePassword, "compositionend")
  
  ie.document.getElementByID("submitButton").Click
End Sub
```

This procedure to trigger the html events:

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

Comment: It works. Can you please help me with which line I have to input to automatically type in my username and password. Lets say my username is "David" and password is "password123"

Comment: I'am not sure if I understand what you mean. You don't want read the username and password from *Sheet1*? Than you can change `username = loginData.Cells(1, "B").Value` to `username = "David"` and `password = loginData.Cells(2, "B").Value` to `password = "password123"`

Comment: Works great. Is there any way that I can now navigate to a different page within the login, to get to the data I would like to extract.

Comment: Sure. You can open every page behind the login by the navigate method of the IE: `ie.Navigate To-The-Url-Behind-Login`. After that you need a manual break too to give the page time to load.

Comment: I would like to extract a line of data from each profile on this website. How would I be able to loop each profile to grab the data from every profile, instead of having a code for each one?

Comment: @DavidMejia I don't know the page. So I can't help you on your question. What is a Profile on that page?

Comment: A profile on this page would practically tell me the start and end time of the engine per vehicle. For Example, Vehicle 1 profile will possibly have a trip 1 start at 6:00 am and end at 7:00 am. Then it will continue to trip 2 starts and end time. For the entire day. It's practically a database for engine start and end times. One of the problems is that each trip information has is set as a drop-down option to view the details.

Comment: However,  the major problem is the way I have to choose the date on the calendar. The Calendar is formated as: <span _ngcontent-tkc-c35="" class="lytx-datepicker__selector__label"><!----><!----> Jul 7, 2020 - Aug 6, 2020 <!----></span> for each date. And is a drop-down calendar

Comment: @DavidMejia Unfortunately it is not possible to infer the functionality of the page by a small html snippet. I assume very much that there will be more html events. But check if the date is in the url after a manual call of the filled out page. Then you can simply use appropriately formatted urls. This also applies to other parameters.